# Nginx: Proxy pass / proxy redirect to shiny web applications

Tags: r, docker, nginx, shiny

We are trying to update our internal server infrastructure and to proxy all accesses to our R shiny webservers through an Nginx server. Im able to get a response from the shiny server but Im not able to get related files like css/js through the Nginx server.

## Setup:

- 2 docker container (1 for hosting nginx, 1 running R for a shiny application)
- both docker container are members of an docker network
- shiny server listens to port 7676 (internal ip-adress 172.18.0.3)
- nginx server is hosting few static html files with iFrames (legacy, cant get ride off), which should show content of the shiny server
- accessing *nginx-server/QueryLandscape.html* loads the page with the iFrame `<iframe src="ilandscape"></iframe>`
- iFrame works: it loads the static part of R-shiny application, but it doesnt load the related JS/CSS/....(e.g. `http://nginx-server:8001/ilandscape/shared/shiny.css`)
- within the nginx-docker container i can access this css file `wget 172.18.0.3:7676/shared/shiny.css`

## Nginx.conf

```
location /ilandscape/ {
    proxy_pass http://172.18.0.3:7676/;
    #proxy_redirect http://172.18.0.3:7676/ $scheme://$host/;

    # websocket headers
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 20d;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

What am I missing in my nginx conf to proxy/redirect `http://nginx-server:8001/ilandscape/shared/shiny.css --> 172.18.0.3:7676/shared/shiny.css` ?

Thanks for your help,
Tobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the iframes acting as a browser are receiving the hostname instead of the full path to the resources. Can you set up the following ReverseProxy headers and give it a go:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Basically you have a proxy at the moment, and we want a reverse proxy too. Let me know if this works.